# Snake. Add the possibility of continuing the game after death

Tags: c#, wpf

Wrote a simple snake.
And I can’t figure out how to add the possibility of continuing the game after death if the player scored a certain number of points. The snake should stop and start moving after clicking on one of the arrow buttons.

[image: Сollision]

In a collision, a window appears about the loss, I need to continue the game. I press the button and the following happens:

[image: this]

I do not understand how I can stop the snake in position, as in 1 photo.

That she would stop, and continue to move only after pressing the arrow buttons.

```
namespace Snake
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //The field on which the snake lives
        Entity field;
        // snake head
        Head head;
        // whole snake
        List<PositionedEntity> snake;
        // apple
        Apple apple;
        //number of points
        int score;
        //time
       DispatcherTimer moveTimer;

        //constructor form
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            snake = new List<PositionedEntity>();
            //create field 600x600pixels
            field = new Entity(600, 600, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/snake.png");

            //create a timer that runs every 300 ms
            moveTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            moveTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
            moveTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(moveTimer_Tick);

        }

        //redraw screen method
        private void UpdateField()
        {
            //update the position of the elements of the snake
            foreach (var p in snake)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(p.image, p.y);
                Canvas.SetLeft(p.image, p.x);
            }

            //update the position of apple
            Canvas.SetTop(apple.image, apple.y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(apple.image, apple.x);

            //points update
            lblScore.Content = String.Format("{0}000", score);
        }

        //timer tick handler. All movement takes place here.
        void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //in the reverse order we move all the elements of the snake
            foreach (var p in Enumerable.Reverse(snake))
            {
                p.move();
            }

            //we check that the head of the snake did not crash into the body
            foreach (var p in snake.Where(x => x != head))
            {
                if (p.x == head.x && p.y == head.y)
                {
                    //we lose
                    moveTimer.Stop();
                    GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    tbScore.Text = String.Format("SCORE: {0}000", score);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //check that the head of the snake did not go out of the field
            if (head.x < 40 || head.x >= 540 || head.y < 40 || head.y >= 540)
            {
                //we lose
                moveTimer.Stop();
                GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                tbScore.Text = String.Format("SCORE: {0}000", score);
                return;
            }

            //check that the head of the snake crashed into an apple
            if (head.x == apple.x && head.y == apple.y)
            {
                //increase the score
                score++;
                //move the apple to a new place
                apple.move();
                var part = new BodyPart(snake.Last());
                canvas1.Children.Add(part.image);
                snake.Add(part);
            }
            UpdateField();
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Up:
                    head.direction = Head.Direction.UP;
                    break;
                case Key.Down:
                    head.direction = Head.Direction.DOWN;
                    break;
                case Key.Left:
                    head.direction = Head.Direction.LEFT;
                    break;
                case Key.Right:
                    head.direction = Head.Direction.RIGHT;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // "Start"
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            tBNotEnoughPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            score = 0;
            snake.Clear();
            canvas1.Children.Clear();
            // "Game Over"
            GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            canvas1.Children.Add(field.image);
            apple = new Apple(snake);
            canvas1.Children.Add(apple.image);
            head = new Head();
            snake.Add(head);
            canvas1.Children.Add(head.image);

            moveTimer.Start();
            UpdateField();

        }
        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (score >= 2)
            {
                GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                score -= 2;

                moveTimer.Start();
                UpdateField();
            }
            else
            {
                tBNotEnoughPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        public class Entity
        {
            protected int m_width;
            protected int m_height;

            Image m_image;
            public Entity(int w, int h, string image)
            {
                m_width = w;
                m_height = h;
                m_image = new Image();
                m_image.Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString(image) as ImageSource;
                m_image.Width = w;
                m_image.Height = h;

            }

            public Image image
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_image;
                }
            }
        }

        public class PositionedEntity : Entity
        {
            protected int m_x;
            protected int m_y;
            public PositionedEntity(int x, int y, int w, int h, string image)
                : base(w, h, image)
            {
                m_x = x;
                m_y = y;
            }

            public virtual void move() { }

            public int x
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_x;
                }
                set
                {
                    m_x = value;
                }
            }

            public int y
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_y;
                }
                set
                {
                    m_y = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Apple : PositionedEntity
        {
            List<PositionedEntity> m_snake;
            public Apple(List<PositionedEntity> s)
                : base(0, 0, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/fruit.png")
            {
                m_snake = s;
                move();
            }

            public override void move()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                do
                {
                    x = rand.Next(13) * 40 + 40 ;
                    y = rand.Next(13) * 40 + 40 ;
                    bool overlap = false;
                    foreach (var p in m_snake)
                    {
                        if (p.x == x && p.y == y)
                        {
                            overlap = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!overlap)
                        break;
                } while (true);

            }
        }

        public class Head : PositionedEntity
        {
            public enum Direction
            {
                RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, UP, NONE
            };

            Direction m_direction;

            public Direction direction {
                set
                {
                    m_direction = value;
                    RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(90 * (int)value);
                    image.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
                }
            }

            public Head()
                : base(280, 280, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/head.png")
            {
                image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                m_direction = Direction.NONE;
            }

            public override void move()
            {
                switch (m_direction)
                {
                    case Direction.DOWN:
                        y += 40;
                        break;
                    case Direction.UP:
                        y -= 40;
                        break;
                    case Direction.LEFT:
                        x -= 40;
                        break;
                    case Direction.RIGHT:
                        x += 40;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public class BodyPart : PositionedEntity
        {
            PositionedEntity m_next;
            public BodyPart(PositionedEntity next)
                : base(next.x, next.y, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/body.png")
            {
                m_next = next;
            }

            public override void move()
            {
                x = m_next.x;
                y = m_next.y;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your code to us? It's not simple when it's a code dump.

Comment: Are you resetting the position of the snake to a valid position? The game ends when the snake hits a wall or itself, do unless you "undo" the thing that ends the game, it will end immediately when you restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a field that determines if the snake should move when the `moveTimer_Tick` is called

```
// Is movement paused
bool paused;
```

Then set this condition when the `Continue` button is pressed.

```
private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (score >= 2)
    {
        GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        score -= 2;

        // Pause movement
        paused = true;

        moveTimer.Start();
        UpdateField();
    }
    else
    {
        tBNotEnoughPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Then check for this in your `moveTimer_Tick` method.

```
//timer tick handler. All movement takes place here.
void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do not update if movement is paused
    if(paused) {
       return;
    }
    ...
}
```

This condition can then be changed when a key is pressed.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Unpause movement when any key is pressed
    if(paused) {
        paused = false;
    }
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Up:
            head.direction = Head.Direction.UP;
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            head.direction = Head.Direction.DOWN;
            break;
        case Key.Left:
            head.direction = Head.Direction.LEFT;
            break;
        case Key.Right:
            head.direction = Head.Direction.RIGHT;
            break;
    }
}
```

You could also expand this to be able to pause the game.

Also you should consider what @Ron Beyer mentioned in his comment:

> The game ends when the snake hits a wall or itself, do unless you "undo" the thing that ends the game, it will end immediately when you restart it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Soenderby has all the specific advice covered so I can only give you my game disclaimer: This looks like WPF. Desktop technologies such as WPF and WindowsForms are not suitable for game design. The XP Style Solitair is about the upper limit of what you can do.

All serious game development requires something that uses a [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure). XNA is a dated option, but there are a [few current ones too](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/gaming). If you wanted to run the Menu but skip the game moving, you would just skip everything between "check for user input" and "draw graphics".

You tried to approximate the Game Loop and the Tick mechanic via a Timer, but that has limits. If you have issues doing something, it is likely out of reach due to that fundamental and very common design mistake.